# MYSQL DELETE rows with multiple exeptions

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a problem with adding exeptions when deleting rows in MYSQL 5.7.

Data table example:
**task_take_over**

```
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
| ID | user_ID | task_ID | year | week |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
| 1  | 16      | 100     | 2018 | 10   |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
| 2  | 16      | 100     | 2018 | 11   |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
| 3  | 16      | 100     | 2018 | 12   |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
| 4  | 16      | 101     | 2018 | 10   |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
| 5  | 16      | 101     | 2018 | 11   |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
| 6  | 16      | 101     | 2018 | 12   |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
| 7  | 16      | 102     | 2018 | 10   |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
| 8  | 16      | 102     | 2018 | 11   |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
| 9  | 16      | 102     | 2018 | 12   |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+
```

Data table example:
**task**

```
+-----+-------------+---------+------------------------+
| ID  | schedule_ID | task    | preference_employee_ID |
+-----+-------------+---------+------------------------+
| 100 | 1           | thing 1 | 15                     |
+-----+-------------+---------+------------------------+
| 101 | 2           | thing 2 | 15                     |
+-----+-------------+---------+------------------------+
| 102 | 3           | thing 3 | 15                     |
+-----+-------------+---------+------------------------+
```

I want to delete ALL rows from task_take_over **except**:

- The rows that JOINS task WITH `schedule_ID = 1` AND WHERE `task.week = 12`

So I have the following query:

```
DELETE task_take_over
FROM task_take_over
JOIN task ON task.ID = task_take_over.task_ID
WHERE task.preference_employee_ID = ?
AND task_take_over.year = ?
/* this part will be looped before executed */
AND (
    task.schedule_ID != ?
    AND task_take_over.week != ?
);
```

The question marks are filled in with: `[15, 2018, 1, 12]`

The problem is that none of the rows with week = 12 will be removed.
All the tasks should be deleted except (`task_take_over.ID = 3`).
Instead `task_take_over.ID = 3`, 6 and 9 will remain undeleted.

It looks like the combination of exceptions between the () are affected for every task_take_over.week. ONLY the combination from schedule_ID and week together should be excluded.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

**[Sql Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b56b3/1)**

```
DELETE task_take_over
FROM task_take_over
LEFT JOIN task 
  ON task_take_over.task_ID = task.ID
 AND schedule_ID = 1 
WHERE schedule_ID IS NULL
  AND week <> 12;
```

**OUTPUT**

You still have `task_id = 100` because those are `schedule_ID = 1`
and also you still have the rows with `week = 12`

```
| ID | user_ID | task_ID | year | week |
|----|---------|---------|------|------|
|  1 |      16 |     100 | 2018 |   10 |
|  2 |      16 |     100 | 2018 |   11 |
|  3 |      16 |     100 | 2018 |   12 |
|  6 |      16 |     101 | 2018 |   12 |
|  9 |      16 |     102 | 2018 |   12 |
```